# Where did the word 'anymore' come from?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

We all know there is a word 'anymore' in English. But is 'somemore' or 'severalmore' exist in English? Why or why not?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Could you please expand your question by saying what would be the meaning of "somemore" and "severalmore"? How would you use them in a sentence, if they existed?

Comment: Oke thanks for your description @CowperKettle, I will clear it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, we do not all know there is a word 'anymore' in English. [It is an American dialect word](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anymore) which would not be commonly written or consider correct in other English dialects. It would be vocalised but written as two words.

The dialect contraction is one of many contractions using the prefix "any". Common forms are *anyone*, *anybody*, *anyhow*, *anything*, *anywhere*. You cannot make new contractions just using the postfix of "more", and as the contraction is a regional dialect, the chances of it occurring in written text are thus low. Further, current spell-checkers would flag it and deter writers from using them.

My spell checker flags *anymore* as incorrect, for example.